# how to force load a new cache

Tags: cache

We have made some changes to the design of our website.
Everything works great and looks good. However, if you haven't deleted your cache since the change, some thing don't look so great.

Is there a way to tell the customers browser not the use their cache?
Maybe something in .htaccess? or somewere else? default magento?

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you [this free extension](https://github.com/jreinke/magento-suffix-static-files). It adds a version number at the end of each css and js. You can control the version number from the backend.
So all you need to do after doing changes in your css and js files is to go to the backend and increment the version number.
This way all your customers will get the latest version of the files and not the ones cached by the browser.